# im having problems to add a calculator, a function that gets dynamicly the operator

Tags: javascript, calculator

someone can help me with some JS basics?

im a rookie, trying to do a calculator, that get the value in the screen, stores it in a variable called previousValue, then the calculator display sets clean and you digit the new number and then when you click equals, its stored in a currentValue variable, and then the operation with previous and current values occours and appear into the display. The issue is i dont know how to set the operator dynamicly to the equals function, that should works by getting the previousValue and operating with the currentValue, whataver the operator is And if i try to change things and do a switch case for each operatorButton.textContent that does the operation there storing in a variable, then when equals() is called just prints this variable on the display.

Things get worst to me, cause i also cant figure out a way to place functions inside de swicth case that calls

get PreviousNumber (a function that gets the number seted on the display and clean it to you digit a new number) and then WAITS till i digit a new number to execute currentNumber function (just gets the number seted in the screen if operator != null)

I dont know if i made things clear, if i didnt, sorry and let me know in the awnsers

here it is the code i have made so far (https://github.com/DanielRKlein/calculator-js)

i've explained above

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] here, not a link. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: When the user clicks on the operator, save it in a variable. When they click on `=` you can use a `switch/case` using that variable to perform the appropriate calculation.

Comment: A link to github may be nice background information, but the code that is subject of your question should be presented inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS object to store data and then use it after with new data and selected operator. Below is draft example of simple calc so you can get general idea. Check inline comments and try demo by clicking `Run code snippet`:

```js
// Display
const disp = document.getElementById("disp");

// Object to store data
let data = {};

// Math operators functions object
const op = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '/': (a, b) => a / b
};

// Calculator function
const calc = v => {
  // Get current value from disp
  let cv = disp.innerText;
  
  //
  // If numbers or dot button pressed,
  // add to disp.
  if(/[\d\.]/.test(v)) {
    // Clear current disp if clear flag is set
    // We need this to run once to start
    // typing second number for math operation
    if(data.clear) {
      delete data.clear;
      cv = 0;
    }
    
    // If current value on display is 0,
    // and input button not dot (.), then
    // remove 0 from disp
    if(cv == '0' && v != '.') cv = '';
    
    // Remove dot if already presented
    if(/\./.test(cv) && v == '.') v = '';
    
    // Inner to display
    disp.innerText = `${cv}${v}`;
  }
  
  //
  // If math operator button is pressed,
  // copy display value and math operator,
  // and set flag to clear disp on next digit input
  if(/[\+\-\*\/]/.test(v)) {
    data.value = cv;
    data.operator = v;
    data.clear = true;
  }
  
  //
  // If = button pressed, check data object
  // for first number and math operator and calculate
  if(/\=/.test(v) && data.value && data.operator) {
    // Calculate with math operators functions object
    // We use math operator as object key, first
    // saved number and current number on display
    // as function parameters. Then inner to display
    disp.innerText = op[data.operator](Number(data.value), Number(cv));

    // Clear data object
    data = {};
  }
  
  //
  // If clear button is pressed, then clear
  // data object and put 0 in to the display
  if(/C/.test(v)) {
    // Clear data object
    data = {};
    
    // Put 0 in to the display
    disp.innerText = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
button {
  width: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="disp">0</div>

<button onclick="calc(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="calc(2)">2</button>
<button onclick="calc(3)">3</button>
<button onclick="calc('/')">÷</button>
<br>
<button onclick="calc(4)">4</button>
<button onclick="calc(5)">5</button>
<button onclick="calc(6)">6</button>
<button onclick="calc('*')">×</button>
<br>
<button onclick="calc(7)">7</button>
<button onclick="calc(8)">8</button>
<button onclick="calc(9)">9</button>
<button onclick="calc('-')">−</button>
<br>
<button onclick="calc(0)">0</button>
<button onclick="calc('.')">.</button>
<button onclick="calc('=')">=</button>
<button onclick="calc('+')">+</button>
<br>
<button onclick="calc('C')">C</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

i understand u used switch to be able to carryout the math operation but if you can merge your the textContent of `#previousOperationText` and `#currentOperationText`  and pass it as an argument to the JS built in eval function;
**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Eval Method</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = eval("4/2");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Result]